# Valid parentheses in Java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays.asList("a+(b*c)-2-a", "(a+b*(2-c)-2+a)*2", "(a*b-(2+c)", "2*(3-a))", ")3+b*(2-c)(")
            .stream().forEach((expression) -> {
                if (replaceAll(expression, "[(]") == replaceAll(expression, "[)]")) {
                    System.out.println("correct");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("incorrect");
                }
            });
}

private static int replaceAll(String word, String regex) {
    int count = word.length() - word.replaceAll(regex, "").length();
    return count;
}
```

I have to check if the expression is valid or not. What determine if an expression is valid or not are the parentheses. If it's self closed, is valid, otherwise, not.

My code is almost correct, it's printing:

```
correct
correct
incorrect
incorrect
correct
```

But it must print

```
correct
correct
incorrect
incorrect
incorrect -> the last expression isn't valid.
```

Comment: Your code only checks if the number of opening parentheseses is the same as the number of closing ones. And that is true for the last expression. What you also need to check is that each opening paranthesis needs to come before a closing one. You won't be able to solve this using regex since the expressions you are trying to check are of a type 2 language in the chomsky hierarchy, while regular expressions are type 3.

Comment: More precisely, you won’t solve it using regexp _alone_. Your solution may include some use of regexp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not only to check if the number of opening parentheses matches the number of closed, but also if each closing parenthesis goes after opening one which isn't "closed" yet:

```
static boolean checkParentheses(String s) {
     int opened = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
         if (s.charAt(i) == '(')
             opened++;
         else if (s.charAt(i) == ')') {
             if (opened == 0)    // means that all parentheses are "closed" yet
                return false;
             opened--;
         }
     }
     return opened == 0;
}
```

If you strictly need regex to be involved, do the following:

```
static boolean checkParentheses(String s) {
    // capture a text starting with one opening parenthesis, 
    // ending with one closing and having no parentheses inside
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\([^()]*\\)");  
    Matcher m;
    while ((m = p.matcher(s)).find())
       s = m.replaceAll("");
    return !(s.contains("(") || s.contains(")"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that it's not enough just to count parentheses; you also need to spot where a ')' comes too early. For example ")(" is not valid even though there are an equal number of opening and closing parentheses.

One approach is to keep a count. Start at zero. Each time you see '(', `count++`. Each time you see ')', `count--`.

After a decrement, `if(count<0)` the input is invalid.

At the end of input, `if(count!0)` the input is invalid.

It's been pointed out that this can't be done in a single regex. That's because a regex represents a **finite** state machine. `count` could in principle increase infinitely.

If you pick a maximum nesting depth, you can write a regex to check it. For example, for a maximum depth of 3:

```
x*(<x*(<x*(<x*>)*x*>)*x*>)*x*
```

(I've used 'x' instead of arbitrary chars here, for readability. Replace it with `[^<>]` to actually match other chars. I've also used `<>` instead of `\(\)` again for readability. The `()` here are for grouping.).

You can always make it work one level deeper by replacing the `x*` in the middle with `x*(<x*>)*x*` -- but you can never made a regex that doesn't stop working at a certain depth.

---

An alternative method is closer to what a real statement parser would do with nested structures: recurse. Something like (pseudocode):

```
def consumeBlock() {
    switch(next char)
       case end-of-input
          throw error -- reached end of input inside some parentheses 
       case '('
          consumeBlock() -- go down a nesting level
          break;
       case ')'
          return -- go up a nesting level
       default
          It's an uninteresting character. Do nothing.
          (a real parser compiler would do something more interesting)
}
```

Here `consumeBlock()` assumes you've just consumed a '(' and you intend to read until its pair.

Some of your inputs don't begin with a '(', so prime it by first appending a ')' to the end, as the pair to a "silent" ')' you're saying it's already consumed.

The pseudocode already shows that if you hit end-of-input mid-block, it's invalid input. Also if you are not at end-of-input when the top-level call to `consumeBlock()` returns, it's invalid input.

Comment: NB Perl's regex implementation has additional features that allows it to count things and to recurse. This means they're not actually "regular expressions" in the mathematical sense. Java is not Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You could go through it char by char and using a counter to tell the parenthesis level in the statement.

```
boolean valid = true;
int level = 0;
for(int i=0; i < expr.length(); i++) {
    if(expr.charAt(i) == '(') level++;
    if(expr.charAt(i) == ')') level--;
    if(level < 0) { // ) with no (
        valid = false; 
        break;
    }
}
if(level > 0) valid = false; // ( with no )
return valid; // true if level returned to 0
```